# Fortran codes won't compile on Mac with gfortran

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I recently moved from the SGI, Sun workstation environment to a Mac. SGI and Sun came with Fortran compilers so I have maybe 100 small f77 codes I wrote over the years for post-processing and analysis of simulated data. I was hoping to get these codes running on my iMac with gfortran. Most of these are very simple codes but I can't get them to compile and execute. I tried starting with the basics and wrote the Hello World code from a gfortran help page.  My code, fortran.f is:

```
program helloworld
print *, "hello world"
end program helloworld
```

When I tried compiling this according to the example I typed:

```
gfortran fortran.f
```

But I keep getting the error message:

```
FATAL:/opt/local/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!
```

This is the same error message I get on my other codes. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can't think of a simpler example but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: How did you install `gfortran` exactly?

Comment: I honestly don't recall. I think MacPorts or Homebrew.  I loaded gfortran years ago but haven't needed it until now.

Comment: Personally, I would be inclined to uninstall it, update Xcode and CommandLine tools and then reinstall. All the underlying linkages and stuff change with each upgrade to macOS. Run `which gfortran` to see which one you have - homebrew will be in /usr/local/bin and MacPorts probably in /opt.

Comment: my which fortran returns /usr/local/bin/gfortran so I assume from your statement I usedHomebrew.  I will attempt to uninstall it and re-install with Homebrew.  Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Upgrade Xcode by running it and checking for updates in the menus and/or by running AppStore and clicking `Updates`. Commandline tools are installed with `xcode-select --install`. Homebrew packages `gfortran` with `GCC`, so you do `brew install gcc` to get it.

Comment: I'm running the latest High Sierra and Xcode with command line tools. Do you still think I need to reload Xcode?

Comment: Probably no need to reload the whole Xcode, just make sure it and CommandLine tools are up-to-date, before reinstalling GCC.

Comment: Thanks. if this works i'll let you know and you can submit it as an answer and i'll select it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Your comment to reinstall gfortran worked. If you want to pose that as an answer I'll be happy to accept it. Thanks for your help on both my questions.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you are up and running. It's late here in the UK, so I'll write it up tomorrow. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `gfortran` was installed a long time ago and you have updated **macOS** since installing, it may need re-installing to get correctly aligned and linked with the latest **macOS** tools and libraries.

My advice would be to:

- uninstall `gfortran`,
- check that Xcode and its command line tools are up-to-date,
- re-install `gfortran`.

Hints for each of those steps follow:

Note that `gfortran` is a part of GCC - the *"GNU Compiler Collection"*.

If you installed `gfortran` via **homebrew**, you can remove it with:

```
brew rm gcc
```

You can update Xcode by by going to **AppStore** and clicking `Updates` at top-right.

The Xcode Command Line tools include `make` and `git` and command-line versions of the compilers. You can install/update the Xcode command line tools with:

```
xcode-select --install
```

You can install `gfortran` with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install gcc
```

When you are finished, you should make sure that your `PATH` includes `/usr/local/bin` near the start and that there are no errors when you run:

```
brew doctor
```

which is a brilliant utility that checks your **homebrew** configuration is correct.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to macOS, I think that building form sources is the best approach you can have. You can achieve that quite easily by downloading and compiling GFortran as part of GCC directly from: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran

However, there are few things you have to take care of:

- make sure you have XCode installed, you can get it here

  [XCode](https://itunes.apple.com/pl/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12)

  XCode is free of charge
- Make sure you have command line tools

  You can get them either from developer.apple.com

  [Command Line Tools](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.1.dmg)

  or directly from XCode. It might be that XCode will tell you to install Command Line Tools upon first execution

  [image]

  In the past, running command like "svn", when Command Line Tools were not installed, also triggered the installation.
- Compile GCC

  ```
  > ./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/usr/local
  > make all
  > make install
  ```
- Alternatively, you can install using macOS package from GFortran

  [gfortran-6.3-Sierra.dmg](http://coudert.name/software/gfortran-6.3-Sierra.dmg)

Fully working sample with Fortran based MPI code:

http://www.owsiak.org/running-open-mpi-on-macos/

Comment: You mean, build GCC from source?

Comment: No, just GFortran

Comment: Fair enough (I was originally going to write gfortran but thought I'd ask wider).  Perhaps  it'd be useful to clarify the gfortran build in the answer?  I originally couldn't tell you meant that, what with the reference to OpenMPI.

Comment: How does one even compile gfortran without GCC? I don't think it is possible. How would you do that? Normally you do --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran and you *cannot* include Fortran without C.

Comment: You are right. I have mixed up things in the answer. Package for macOS (which I use from time to time) and GCC sources (which I also use in some cases).

Comment: @mko Thanks for your answer.  I discovered the Gfortran binaries last night while trying unsuccessfully to install gcc via Homebrew. It solved my problems. Very nice.

Comment: .oOo. Cool. Have fun with Fortran! .oOo.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was change the path.

Initially, my PATH was something like

/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin

Because of this reason, the default assembler (as) was not called which is in the /usr/bin directory.

To enable the call to the right assembler (as), I had to add /usr/bin to the PATH in front of (before) /opt/local/bin, i.e. on a Mac this can be added by editing ~/.bash_profile such that one's $PATH looks like

/usr/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin

Once edited, execute at your command prompt:

source /etc/bash_profile

This worked for me.