# Sublimetext 3 doesn't work with gfortran

Tags: build, fortran, sublimetext3, gfortran

I am trying to run Fortran in SublimeText on Windows 10.

I have installed MinGW and so I expected to have gfortran installed. But it doesn't work in SublimeText 3 even though there is a possibility to build with gfortran. My code is like this:

```
program Hi
    write(*,*) "Hello"
end program Hi
```

But it gives me this error:

> gfortran: error: 'C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Hi.f90': Invalid argument

When I try to run it in cmd, it does nothing

[image]

Can anyone help me to make it run?

Comment: Your example from cmd looks like it compiled the code successfully. There would be an error message when the `gfortran` command is not found or when gfortran encounters a problem. Perhaps related? It is an old and fixed bug though https://github.com/315234/SublimeFortran/issues/12

Comment: Do you actually use this plugin https://github.com/315234/SublimeFortran ?

Comment: Now I did use the plugin, but in cmd "git" is not recognized as command.

Comment: Git must be installed first https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/InstallMSysGit

Comment: Installed and tried it, but now it doesn't write anything in the sublime text output.

Comment: I couldn't get gfortran to run in Sublimetext either. I kept getting an error message 'FATAL:/opt/local/bin/../libexec/as/x86_64/as: I don't understand 'm' flag!  There were no flags set.  I asked a similar question and got this answer"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174684/fortran-codes-wont-compile-on-mac-with-gfortran/49920545#49920545

Comment: This worked for me. I had installed gfortran with homebrew.