# Installing gfortran via macports on Mac OS high sierra

Tags: macos, gcc, fortran, gfortran, macports

My supervisor has asked that I install a fortran compiler on my mac and suggested using MacPorts to install gcc6. I have tried to install gcc6 a number of times but each time it doesn't seem to come with `gfortran`. No matter what I do I cannot seem to figure out what is going on and how to get around it.

Any hep on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the command used to install gcc:

```
sudo port install gcc6
```

Comment: I prefer **homebrew** over **Macports**, and I just checked that the `gcc` package includes `gfortran`. It does.

Comment: I agree, **homebrew** over **Macports**. Did you install xCode and the xCode command line developer tools? I think they are required for homebrew's installation. Maybe Macports is that way too.

Comment: from my research I also believe homebrew is better but I had already started using macports at my supervisors recommendation and I've been told that the two don't play well together. I've installed all of the xcode tools as used them before.

Comment: If you are not forced to use macports, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174684/fortran-codes-wont-compile-on-mac-with-gfortran/48183650#48183650

Comment: Do you mean to distinguish between gcc (the compiler suite) and gcc (the C compiler)?

Comment: What makes you think you don't have gfortran?

Answer (score 11):

**MacPorts** allows you to have multiple versions of gcc installed. Before you get `gfortran` executable you have to select the default version.

First - install gcc:

```
sudo port install gcc9
```

After this command you will have gfortran under `gfortran-mp-9` alias. To make `gfortran-mp-9` the default and make it reachable via `gfortran` command do:

```
sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc9
```

---

The examples above assumed `gcc9`, but you might need adjust the above gcc version to the one you need to work with.

Comment: This was vital in helping me get the right MacPorts package to install some random R package I needed for a workshop (that had hard-coded `/opt/local/bin/gfortran-mp-9` in its build scripts or something). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With macports the correct command to install fortran would be

```
sudo port install gcc6 +gfortran
```

This will install `gfortran`. You may want to refer to the [gfortran manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran.pdf) along with other Fortran references you may be using.

Note: You may choose some other version of gcc, of course. You can search for which versions are available on the [macports site](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=gcc).

Comment: I had to combine these two answers as follows: `sudo port install gcc11 +gfortran; sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc11`