# Installing pymc on Mac OS 10.14.5

Tags: python-3.x, gfortran, pymc

I'm attempting to install pymc on MacOS 10.14.5 Mojave. However, there seems to be a problem with the gfortran module. The error message is minimally helpful.

I have attempted all the possible ways to install pymc as suggested here: https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/INSTALL.html

I first came across a problem with not recognising f951 in my gfortran compiler, but I solved that by adding the path to f951 explicitly to my `PATH`.

Now I come across the following after a bunch of warning messages in `pymc.flib.f`:

```
ld: unknown option: -idsym

error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -m64 -Wall -g -undefined dynamic_lookup -bundle build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/cephes/i0.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/cephes/c2f.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/cephes/chbevl.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/build/src.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pymc/flibmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/build/src.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/build/src.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pymc/fortranobject.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pymc/flib.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pymc/histogram.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pymc/flib_blas.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pymc/blas_wrap.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pymc/math.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pymc/gibbsit.o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/build/src.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pymc/flib-f2pywrappers.o -L/Users/cameron/anaconda3/lib -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0/8.3.0 -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0/8.3.0/../../.. -L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18.5.0/8.3.0/../../.. -lmkl_rt -lpthread -lgfortran -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.7/pymc/flib.cpython-37m-darwin.so" failed with exit status 1
```

No online searches reveal what might cause the exit status 1 with gfortran.

Comment: Did you try re-installing `gfortran` ? This thread suggests doing that if you had your `gfortran` installed a while ago https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184252/7841468

Comment: Yes! This worked, thank you so much. I'll put this as the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to @mishsx for suggesting re-installing gfortran. This is something I had done previously but this time I used homebrew, as explained here: stackoverflow.com/a/48184252/7841468

I went into my /usr/local/ and /usr/local/bin/ and deleted the gfortran folders since I had not previously installed gfortran with homebrew. One small problem was that the path was not included the first time I used homebrew, so I removed it with brew rm gcc, then reinstalled with brew install gcc.

The pymc installation then went ahead without error.

Comment: Thank you sir :) Glad I could help you with your query :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this can usually be fixed by purging your gfortran install and switching to brew fully.

However, the underlying issue is actually being caused by not having a valid `collect2` (part of GCC) available to your gfortran. This causes the spec to pass flags to `ld` (only `collect2` understands `-idsym`/`-dsym`).

I'm mostly noting this as a classic broken gfortran example.

Comment: Note that these flags are not documented by `/full/path/to/collect2 --help`, so you would have to look [at the source](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/fe3e978027724f28d3e15747c991844793d42922/gcc/collect2.cc#L2991-L3002) to guess what they do(!)